# Does this sentence contain a redundant "a"?

Tags: traducción

It seems to me that this sentence:

```
"Este dinero se lo dio a a Dill, ...."
```

...from the translation of "To Kill a Mockingbird" ("Matar a un ruisenor") contains a redundant "a".

If not, what is the reason for the doubled "a"?

Comment: Again a mistake; it should be with a single "a".

Comment: Correct. Mistake. Should be just one "a".

Comment: Anyone can teach me what the sentence means? The money gave it to Dill...?

Comment: I think it's "this money was given to Dill" (Dill is a cat, not a pickle; and by "cat" I mean a guy, not a feline/gato).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, that's an error. It should be

> Este dinero se lo dio **a** Dill, ...